# How can I dynamically change the Active Record database for all models in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

In our program, each customer gets their own database.  We e-mail them a link that connects them to their database.  The link contains a GUID that lets the program know which database to connect to.

How do I dynamically and programatically connect ActiveRecord to the right db?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can also do this easily without hardcoding anything and run migrations automatically:

```
customer = CustomerModel.find(id)
spec = CustomerModel.configurations[RAILS_ENV]
new_spec = spec.clone
new_spec["database"] = customer.database_name
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(new_spec)
ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrate("db/migrate_data/", nil)
```

I find it useful to re-establish the old connection on a particular model afterwards:

```
CustomerModel.establish_connection(spec)
```

Answer (score 16):

you can change the connection to ActiveRecord at any time by calling ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(...)

IE:

```
 ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection({:adapter => "mysql", :database => new_name, :host => "olddev",
    :username => "root", :password => "password" })
```

Comment: Note that this will clear your cache - so it'll do a 'Show tables like %eachtable%' and show create table' for each table.  Only a problem if you're making a new connection on each request...

Answer (score 14):

It's been a while since this question has been created, but I have to say that there is another way too:

```
conn_config = ActiveRecord::Base.connection_config.to_h.deep_dup
conn_config[:database] = new_database
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection conn_config
```

Comment: this saved my life! great simplified answer!

Comment: how change connstring without affect another pool?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I'm almost sure `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection` creates a new pool. If you have a specific issue, you'll have more benefit opening a new question.

Comment: Use `ActiveRecord::Base.connection_config.to_h.deep_dup` to avoid `FrozenError: can't modify frozen Hash`.

Answer (score 4):

```
class Database
  def self.development!
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:development)
  end

  def self.production!
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(ENV['PRODUCTION_DATABASE'])
  end

  def self.staging!
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(ENV['STAGING_DATABASE'])
  end
end
```

And in `.env` (with `dotenv-rails` gem for instance):

```
PRODUCTION_DATABASE=postgres://...
STAGING_DATABASE=postgres://...
```

And now you can:

```
Database.development!
User.count
Database.production!
User.count
Database.staging!
User.count
# etc.
```