# Rails multiple databases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have a Rails application which (for some reason) needs to connect to multiple databases. I know I can use ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection but the problem is that the database name could be one of many names with the same prefix. I.e db_001, db_002, etc. I the "001", "002" numbers are to be passed to the model from a controller and are based on the current application flow.

Question: Is it possible to pass a database name as a parameter to establish_connection, like this?

```
class Some < ActiveRecord::Base
 establish_connection ({
    :adapter  => "mysql2",
    :username => "name",
    :password => "pass"
    :database => "db_#{THE_PASSED_VALUE}"
 })
end
```

These specific databases (db_001, db_002, ...) will be used only by this one model.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

in rails 2.3.x there is

database_name from ActiveRecord::Base.

This looks similar to [How can I dynamically change the Active Record database for all models in Ruby on Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180349/how-can-i-dynamically-change-the-active-record-database-for-all-models-in-ruby-o)